# How to remove this HEADER HTTP?

Tags: c, sockets, http, http-headers

I made a socket in C. This program is operated by command line and compiled on Linux. It does the following:

- Takes a a full URI and a file name
- Connects to a server, retrieves the page and saved in the specified file.
- After obtaining the remote data. The file received by the recv function comes with a HEADER.

My question is:

How to remove this HEADER before the file is recorded by the fwrite () function.
like a byte to byte code, to find a double line "\ n \ n".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need a 2-step solution. Receive just the response headers by themselves first (which you have to do anyway in order to detect how the response body is encoded before you can receive it), then receive and decode the body and write it to your file.  Better yet, stop doing this manually and use an existing HTTP library that handles these details for you, such as libcurl.

Comment: Doing this wouldn't be sufficient anyway; you'll also need to undo Transfer Codings and likely Content Codings to obtain a usable response body.

Answer (score 5):

An HTTP header always ends in `\r\n\r\n`. Therefore you just want to find the first string match of that, and increment the position by 4 bytes.

### strstr() function

The [`strstr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) function (found in `string.h`) does just this:

```
char * strstr(const char *str1, const char *str2);
```

Where `str2` is the string you're searching for in `str1`.

It returns the memory location to the *beginning* of the first match. If the string is not found it returns `NULL`.

### Example

So, if you assume the buffer is larger than the header:

```
char *buf = getHTTPResponse(url); // Get HTTP response from URL
char *content = strstr(buf, "\r\n\r\n");
if (content != NULL) {
    content += 4; // Offset by 4 bytes to start of content
}
else {
    content = buf; // Didn't find end of header, write out everything
}

// Write out content to file
```

See [here](http://coding.debuntu.org/c-linux-socket-programming-tcp-simple-http-client) for a complete HTTP client example in C that uses `strstr()`.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to read the *complete* response into a string, as this answer suggests.  A streaming solution would be safer, faster, and more efficient.